# When versioning via modules, why isn't me method being recognized and sending a NoMethodError?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, versioning, nomethoderror

In controllers/api/v1/sessions_controller.rb I have...

```
module Api
    module V1
        class SessionsController < ApplicationController
            respond_to :json
            skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token

            def create
                @user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
                if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
                    token = User.new_remember_token
                    sign_in @user, token
```

and then in helpers/api/v1/sessions_helper.rb I have...

```
module Api
    module V1
        module SessionsHelper
            def sign_in (user, token)
                user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.digest(token))
                self.current_user = user
            end
        end
    end
end
```

When I attempt to POST to Sessions, I get the following error.

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `sign_in' for #<Api::V1::SessionsController:0x0000010324d278>):
  app/controllers/api/v1/sessions_controller.rb:12:in `create'
```

Why am I getting this error? Is this not correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods defined in `helper` classes of a `resource` are directly accessible **only in corresponding views**(of the same resource) and **NOT in controller**, so you  would need to include the `helper` module **explicitly** in the controller in order to access these helper methods.

```
module Api
    module V1
        class SessionsController < ApplicationController
          include Api::V1::SessionsHelper ## Add this
          ## ...
        end
    end
end
```

You are getting the error because `Api::V1::SessionsController` has no idea about the existence of `sign_in` method.